# I wrote a code to update the Lettering of the first name in Zoho but it's not working

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge, deluge

Here's the deluge script to capitalize the first letter of the sentence and make the other letters small that isn't working:

```
a = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Contacts",input.ID);

d = a.get("First_Name");

firstChar = d.subString(0,1);

otherChars = d.removeFirstOccurence(firstChar);

Name = firstChar.toUppercase() + otherChars.toLowerCase();

mp = map();

mp.put("First_Name",d);

b = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Contacts", Name,{"First_Name":"Name"});

info Name;

info b;
```

I tried capitalizing the first letter of the alphabet and make the other letters small. But it isn't working as expected.

Comment: Zoho deluge has a function called proper that returns the string with the first character in each word in upper case, and all other characters in lower case. https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/functions/string/proper.html

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the double-quotes from the Name value in the the following statement. The reason is that `Name` is your variable holding the case-adjusted name, but `"Name"` is the string "Name".

From:

`b = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Contacts", Name,{"First_Name":"Name"});`

To

`b = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Contacts", Name,{"First_Name":Name});`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [concat](https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/functions/string/concat.html)

```
Name = firstChar.toUppercase().concat( otherChars.toLowerCase() );
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
sentence = "salsalIn mOoKo sIge NA";
capitilize_first_char_every_word = sentence.proper();
capitilize_only_first_char_of_sentence = sentence.subString(0,1).toUpperCase().concat(sentence.subString(1,sentence.toList("").size()).toLowerCase());


info capitilize_first_char_every_word;
info capitilize_only_first_char_of_sentence;
```

Info result should be :

```
Salsalin Mooko Sige Na
Salsalin mooko sige na
```

You can try this script in https://dre.zoho.com/tryout

Answer (score 0):

Your code put 'd' into "First_Name" but 'd' wasn't cleansed. You also don't need a map as you are updating with the key/value in the update Record. Try this...

*Set argument of contactId*

```
contactRec = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Contacts",contactId);

firstChar = contactRec.get("First_Name").subString(0,1);

otherChars = contactRec.get("First_Name").removeFirstOccurence(firstChar);

firstName = firstChar.toUppercase() + otherChars.toLowerCase();

updateContact = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Contacts", contactId,{"First_Name":Name});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = zoho.crm.getRecordById("Contacts",cId);

d = a.get("First_Name");

firstChar = d.subString(0,1);

otherChars = d.removeFirstOccurence(firstChar);

Name = firstChar.toUppercase() + otherChars.toLowerCase();

mp = Map();

mp.put("First_Name",Name);

update = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Contacts", cId, mp);
```